# Set the UUID and User ID into the current request thread

Tags: java, spring

I would like to enhance my production logging for my rest application. Is there anyway I can access the current request thread to perform the following:

- Generate an UUID for each request
- Get the username
- Put both the UUID and username into the thread

This is allow me to view the details via logging or jstack.

Comment: Where do you want to get the username from? Do you use Spring security?

Comment: yes, I am using Spring Security

Comment: We can put all the details into ThreadLocal - It is data specific to the current thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: have you considered using spring sleuth (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth), which offers tracing functionality for distributed systems?

Comment: @Gernot, no. I prefer to keep my implementations simplified.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything fair enough. maybe you want to have a look at it at a later point when you need more features for tracing calls within your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Spring Security You could use SecurityContextHolder from Spring

```
User user = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
String name = user.getUsername(); //get logged in username
```

And then use JDK function for generating UUID

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID()
```

**Updated**

I would not recommend to use thread local for storing this info, ideally you could store this info in current http session. If you use stateless session you could use session provided by your auth server and use access token to store this information. Most of the auth services aloud to create custom fields in the access token.

Comment: but how do I associate these information with the thread/request?

Comment: Just call it in your logic. Servlet containers work as "thread per request" so every user would be in separate thread anyway. If you do want to get thread info you could also get current thread ID - Thread.currentThread().getId();

Comment: Put that in a filter and assuming you use slf4j as an API for logging put it in the MDC. Then you can log it quite simple.

Comment: @AliakseiStadnik If I were to store it in the session, all the requests will have the same uuid.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, that's one way I thought of, but I would like to find out if there is any "spring way" of implementing it, like using interceptor?

Comment: What isn't spring like with that. It will work for every request, whereas an interceptor will only work for anything handled by a controller. You would basically implement the same but in a different component.

Comment: If for any reasons you do not want to use filter you could use Request scope of Spring. Implement some bean with this functionality and make the scope as Request.

Comment: @M.Deinum can I get Spring user from the filter?

Comment: If the filter is executed after the Spring Security filter you can. You could create 2 filters, 1 for the request UUID (which would execute very early) and the user one which executes after the Spring Security filter.